# How can I add altmetrics badge to in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, cross-reference

I am trying to use altmetrics in one of the my article (PDF) in my website.

I tried to add the altmetric badges ([here](https://api.altmetric.com/embeds.html)) to in reacts js but I could not manage.

Here is my trial:

First I tried to create a component and add to the page

```
class DownloadPDF extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js"></script>
        <div data-badge-details="right" data-badge-type="medium-donut" data-doi={"my-doi-number-here"} class="altmetric-embed">&#160;</div>
        <a href = "my-crosreff-doi.pdf" target = "_blank">Download PDF </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The second is I tried to put in the page directly:

```
      <div>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js"></script>
                  <div data-badge-details="right" data-badge-type="medium-donut" data-doi="my-doi-number-here" class="altmetric-embed"> my-crosreff-doi.pdf</div>
                  {<DownloadPDF />}


</div>
```

Can someone know how can I put altmetrics badges correctly in reactJS?

Comment: here {<DownloadPDF />} curly braces not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all answers.

For seeing the `Altmetrics` result in your page first you should add:

1. altmetrics external javascript file

   `<script type='text/javascript'src='https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js'></script>`

2.
You should add your DOI wherever you want to display

```
<div class='altmetric-embed' data-badge-type='donut' data-doi="10.1038/nature.2012.9872"></div>
```

so this is for adding to html page but when you add in `ReactJS` web app we have a tiny problem.

Problem is adding external javascript file to in ReactJS page that you want to display the `Altmetrics badge`

So solution is we need to install an addition library that allows us to implement any external javascript file.

Check the link:
https://github.com/shaneosullivan/ReactDependentScript/

We need to add below code in your ReactJS page

```
...
render() {

    return (

<div>
<ReactDependentScript
  loadingComponent={<div></div>}
  scripts={['https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js']}
>
  <div></div>
</ReactDependentScript>

...

</div>

    );
  }

}
```

then you can add your the Altmetrics badge wherever you want in the page like this

```
<div data-badge-details="right" data-badge-type="medium-donut" data-doi="doi-numberhere" class="altmetric-embed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do as described https://api.altmetric.com/embeds.html 
that you put the js script in any where in html , but react is virtual dom , so all you need is put in puplic in index.html in `<body> under <div id"root"></div>`
or like you named. just simple as that

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you are missing

1. Adding the script to `index.html file under`public`directory (if you have created your app using`create-react-app`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <!-- Here we go with the external script -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js'></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Change the `class` attribute to `className` in dom

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        // changed class to className
        <div className='altmetric-embed' data-badge-type='donut' data-doi="10.1038/nature.2012.9872"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but unfortunately still same

Comment: You are welcome @Axis : actually I have tried it in my dev and I was able to see the badge. What issue you are having, is it not loading up?

Comment: I cannot see the donut in my page. I am missing something

Comment: Which console? I am using VScode and with no any error also I am using localhost. I can see everything is fine but only I cannot see the altmetrics donut

Comment: It's the browser console.